# How to get a value from each ListView Items in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this thing out, I hope someone can help me. Please see the image below.

http://s30.postimg.org/72iyqzbi9/image.jpg

What I wanna do is that to get the "quantity" of each item in my ListView so that I can subtract it to my current product stock, What I have tried so far.. Please see the code below

```
Dim val1 As Double
Dim val2 As Double
Dim curstock As Double         
i.SubItems.Add(TB_PI_ProductStock.Text)
val1 = TB_QQuantity.Text
val2 = TB_PI_ProductStock.Text
currentstock = val2 - val1
i.SubItems.Add(currentstock)
```

Because I'm having a hard time to get the values of my ListView items, What I did was, I query the "current stock quantity" of each Item that I'm going to add in my ListView but the results was not accurate and not good..

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  The LV and TB can only hold strings/text which are not numbers.  The DataGridView is a much better choice for this sort of thing (it has actual columns, not subitems.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want this:

```
  'declare your list of Quantity
    Dim Quantity as List(Of Double)

   'add your itmes (from picture 1 and 5) 
     Quantity.add(1)
     Quantity.add(5)

  'get your items  
 For Each QuantityList As double In Quantity 
    'some action like below
     MessageBox.Show(QuantityList.ToString)

Next
```

If this is not what you wanted then add more information

Comment: umm, No. what I wanna do is like this, Product1 has 100 current stock then I added Product1 in my ListView with 2 quantity, I want to subtract the quantity of the Product to my current stock which is 100, so the equation would be (CurrentStockofTheProduct) - (ProductQuantity) = 98 Current Stock, I can't do that because I don't know how to get the value of the ListView, and how can I do that with all the other ListViewItems, I hope you got me..

Comment: @Kyle please update you question with this information and if you try something show it